# PonyORM - multiple model files

Tags: python, ponyorm

I want to separate my model classes into separate files in a models directory.  I would like to have a separate file for:

- general (authentication and global classes/tables)
- requisitions (tables used for requisitions)
- workorders (tables used for workorders)
- sales_orders (tables used for sales orders)
- ...etc

I'm not sure how to structure my project to make that happen.

I've tried putting my main imports into **init**.py in the directory and them importing those into the individual model files, but I don't know where to put my db.generate_mapping() so that all classes are available.  I'm guessing this is a best practice for a large application.  I've got about 150 tables in my app at this point.

Any help/pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the following project structure:

```
# /myproject
#     settings.py
#     main.py
#     /models
#         __init__.py
#         base.py
#         requisitions.py
#         workorders.py
#         sales_orders.py
```

`settings.py` is a file with database settings:

```
# settings.py
db_params = {'provider': 'sqlite', 'filename': ':memory:'}
```

`main.py` is a file when you start application. You put `db.generate_mapping` here:

```
# main.py
from pony import orm
import settings
from models import db
from your_favorite_web_framework import App

# orm.set_sql_degug(True)
db.bind(**settings.db_params)
db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)

with orm.db_session:
    orm.select(u for u in db.User).show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.run()
```

Note that it is not necessary to implicitly import all models, as they are accessible as attributes of `db` object (like `db.User`)

You can put `db` object in `base.py` (or `general.py`), where you define your core models:

```
# base.py
from pony import orm

db = orm.Database()

class User(db.Entity):
    name = Required(str)
    orders = Set('Order')
```

Note that in `User` model I can refer to `Order` model defined in another module. You can also write it as

```
    orders = Set(lambda: db.Order)
```

Unfortunately, IDEs like PyCharm at this moment cannot recognize that `db.Order` refers to specific `Order` class. You can import and use `Order` class directly, but in some cases it will lead to problem with cyclic imports.

In other model files you import `db` from `.base`:

```
# workorders.py
from pony import orm
from .base import db

class Order(db.Entity):
    description = Optional(str)
    user = Required('User')
```

In `/models/__init__.py` you import all modules to ensure that all models classes are defined before `generate_mapping` is called:

```
# /models/__init__.py
from .base import db
from . import workorders
...
```

And then you can write

```
from models import db
```

And access models as `db` attributes like `db.User`, `db.Order`, etc.

If you want to refer models directly in your code instead of accessing them as `db` attributes, you can import all models in `__init__.py`:

```
# /models/__init__.py
from .base import db, User
from .workorders import Order
...
```

And then you can import model classes as:

```
from models import db, User, Order, ...
```