# When using Pony ORM or sqlalchemy, where to create Database object?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, ponyorm

I began playing a bit with Object Relational Mappers (*Pony ORM* specifically).

In *Pony*, all entity definitions inherit from the [`db.Entity`](https://docs.ponyorm.com/api_reference.html#Database.Entity) class. However in order to do that of course the `db` object needs to be created first somewhere. (`db.Entity` is somewhat similar to the declarative base in *sqlalchemy*, so I believe my question below is also similar valid for *sqlalchemy*)

All the examples I have seen in the Pony ORM docs present the examples inline, where the Database object `db` is simply declared in the interpreter prompt before the entities are declared.

This leaves for me the question: **Where should I create my db object in a "real" project?.**

Especially consider the case where I want to keep my entity definitions separate from where I actually use these entities (say I only want to build a nice ORM wrapper package to access a database, which then should be used in multiple different other projects). Then I probably want the users to provide the own `db` object that is configured to their needs in order to access the DB.

### Some example code:

Say I have a Database that stores *persons* and *addresses* and my package `my_orm` should provide an ORM for the database, which then will be used in `app.py`:

*my_orm/**init**.py*

```
from my_orm.person import Person
from my_orm.address import Address
```

*my_orm/person.py:*

```
from pony.orm import Required

class Person(db.Entity): # Where should `db` be defined?
    name = Required(str)
    age = Required(int)
```

*my_orm/address.py:*

```
from pony.orm import Required

class Address(db.Entity): # Where should `db` be defined?. Must be the same `db` object as in person.py
    street_name = Required(str)
    zip_code = Required(int)
```

*app.py*

```
from pony.orm import Database
db = Database()
import my_orm
```

Besides already looking ugly because it mixes the imports with the creation of the db, this will also throw the error `NameError: name 'db' is not defined`. So what should I do instead?

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to organize the code.

### 1. Place all entities in a single file

This is a convenient way for simple and medium-sized projects. It is the simplest and probably you can start this way. You can define `Database` object in this file right before entity definitions:

*models.py*

```
from pony.orm import Database, Required, Optional

db = orm.Database()

class Person(db.Entity):
    name = Required(str)
    addresses = Set('Address') # or Set(lambda: Address)

class Address(db.Entity):
    street_name = Required(str)
    persons = Set('Person')
```

*main.py*

```
from models import db, Person, Address
from settings import db_params
from pony.orm import db_session, select

db.bind(**db_params)
db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)

with db_session:
    persons = select(p for p in Person if p.age > 20)[:]
```

This way is simple and suitable for medium-sized projects, you can start with it

### 2. Define entities inside a function

This may be useful if you want to connect to several different instances of `Database` in the same program

*models.py*

```
from pony.orm import Required, Optional

def define_entities(db):
    class Person(db.Entity):
        name = Required(str)
        addresses = Set('Address')

    class Address(db.Entity):
        street_name = Required(str)
        persons = Set('Person')
```

*main.py*

```
from models import define_entities
from settings import db_params
from pony.orm import Database, db_session, select

db = Database()
define_entities(db)
db.bind(**db_params)
db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)

with db_session:
    persons = select(p for p in db.Person if p.age > 20)[:]
```

Note that it is possible to access entity classes as properties of a Database object: `db.Person`. It may be convenient, as it is not necessary to import the `Person` entity -- it is enough to have access to the `db` object. The drawback is that IDEs like PyCharm don't understand what `db.Person` is and don't provide suggestions for code completion of attributes like `Person.name`.

It is also possible to split entiti definitions between several functions which are imported from different files:

*models1.py*

```
from pony.orm import Required, Optional

def define_entities(db):
    class Person(db.Entity):
        name = Required(str)
        addresses = Set('Address') # or: Set(lambda: db.Address)
```

*models2.py*

```
from pony.orm import Required, Optional

def define_entities(db):
    class Address(db.Entity):
        street_name = Required(str)
        persons = Set('Person')  # or: Set(lambda: db.Person)
```

*main.py*

```
import models1, models2
from settings import db_params
from pony.orm import Database, db_session, select

db = Database()
models1.define_entities(db)
models2.define_entities(db)
db.bind(**db_params)
db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)

with db_session:
    persons = select(p for p in db.Person if p.age > 20)[:]
```

This is probably overkill, but can sometimes be used for a pluggable architecture, when exact set of entities is defined dynamically after the application start.

### 3. Define entities in separate files (not inside the function)

You can follow the schema that I described in the corresponding answer:
[PonyORM - multiple model files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51601838/ponyorm-multiple-model-files/51671065#51671065)

Answer (score 1):

You can use metaclasses for defining entities.

file 1:

```
class LazyEntityMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
        entity = mcs._entities[name] = LazyEntity(bases, attrs)
        return entity

    @classmethod
    def attach(mcs, db):
        for name, lazy in mcs._entities.items():
            lazy.entity = type(name, lazy.bases + (db.Entity,), attrs)

    _entities = {}

class LazyEntity:
    def __init__(self, bases, attrs):
        self.bases = bases
        self.attrs = attrs
```

file 2:

```
class A(metaclass=LazyEntityMeta):
    id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
```

file 3:

```
db = Database()

LazyEntityMeta.attach(db)
db.bind('sqlite', ':memory:')
db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)

with db_session:
    a1 = db.A()
    a2 = A.entity()
```