# Can I use pony orm with models in separate files?

Tags: ponyorm

Is it possible to use Pony with a file structure like this?

```
-project/
    -start.py
    -controller/
    -view/
    -model/
        __init__.py
        -person.py
        -category.py
```

All examples I have seen were single file setups like this:

```
db = Database()

class Person(db.Entity):
    ...

class Category(db.Entity):
    ...

db.bind(...)
db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)
```

I want to move the class declarations to the model folder.

Answer (score 0):

Thank goodness for the related questions section. It looks like this question has already been asked and answered: [PonyORM - multiple model files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51601838/ponyorm-multiple-model-files/51671065#51671065). Thank you to Alexander Kozlovsky for providing a detailed answer to that question.

My summary of Alexander Kozlovsky's answer:

1. Have a file somewhere

```
# database.py
from pony.orm import *

db = Database()
```

2. In the model files, do `from database import db`.
3. Wherever `db.generate_mapping()` is, import all your models at the top of that file.